# Call injected service inside call back function

Tags: angular, electron, this, angular-services

I am developing an Electron/Angular 13 application

I have the following function :

```js
async handleStop(e: any) {
    const blob = new Blob(this.recordChunks, {
        type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
    });
    
    const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());
    console.log(buffer)

    this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send('stop-recording', buffer);
}
```

I am using it as a callback function like this :

```js
async onSourceSelected(displayId: string) {
    let constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: displayId
            }
        }
    };

    // CREATE A STREAM
    let stream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as  any).getUserMedia(constraints);
    
    // Create the media Recorder
    const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    
    // Register event handler
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.handleDataAvailable;
    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.handleStop;
};
```

The constructor of the component:

```js
constructor(private dialogRef: DialogRef, @Inject(DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private _electronService: ElectronApiServiceService, private zone: NgZone, private dialog: DialogService) { }
```

The "_electronService"  is an Angular service injected in the component's constructor. When the "handleStop" method is called, I get the following error in the console :

> "Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'ipcRenderer') ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'ipcRenderer')"

Comment: Can you add whole component code, including constructor with service?

Comment: I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind your event handler to `this` explicitly. When you assign `handleStop` to the `onstop`, it loses the context, so the `this` inside the `handleStop` function doesn't refer to the object itself.

```
this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.handleStop.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response . Your solution resolved the error But all objects inside the function are empty , I updated The code of the function and added more details. When I use your solution the "buffer' object is empty . but when i remove what you siggested , it contains  the data.